# SAP HANA insert data from SAPUI5 issue

Tags: sapui5, hana, cds, sap-cap

I have to add a some data to HANA entity excelFile.
But I don't know how to add it.
I'm learning SAP BTP HANA CDS development.
I developed an SAP CDS app and connected a SAPUI5 app with that.
But when trying to add data from the front end it generates some errors as follows

error

```
[odata] - POST /odata/v4/my/excelFile 
----------------------------creating...................
{
  exId: 9876,
  exEmail: 'dfg',
  exFirst_name: 'dg',
  exLast_name: 'fdqf',
  exAvatar: 'fg'
}
[cds] - IllegalArgumentError: The key 'exId' does not exist in the given entity
    at UriHelper.buildEntityKeys (/home/user/projects/MyHANAApp/node_modules/@sap/cds/libx/_runtime/cds-services/adapter/odata-v4/okra/odata-server/utils/UriHelper.js:87:17)
    at ResponseHeaderSetter.setLocationHeader (/home/user/projects/MyHANAApp/node_modules/@sap/cds/libx/_runtime/cds-services/adapter/odata-v4/okra/odata-server/core/ResponseHeaderSetter.js:102:17)
    at SetResponseHeadersCommand.execute (/home/user/projects/MyHANAApp/node_modules/@sap/cds/libx/_runtime/cds-services/adapter/odata-v4/okra/odata-server/invocation/SetResponseHeadersCommand.js:66:30)
    at CommandExecutor._execute (/home/user/projects/MyHANAApp/node_modules/@sap/cds/libx/_runtime/cds-services/adapter/odata-v4/okra/odata-server/invocation/CommandExecutor.js:71:17)
    at /home/user/projects/MyHANAApp/node_modules/@sap/cds/libx/_runtime/cds-services/adapter/odata-v4/okra/odata-server/invocation/CommandExecutor.js:81:18
    at ConditionalRequestControlCommand.execute (/home/user/projects/MyHANAApp/node_modules/@sap/cds/libx/_runtime/cds-services/adapter/odata-v4/okra/odata-server/invocation/ConditionalRequestControlCommand.js:48:5)
    at CommandExecutor._execute (/home/user/projects/MyHANAApp/node_modules/@sap/cds/libx/_runtime/cds-services/adapter/odata-v4/okra/odata-server/invocation/CommandExecutor.js:71:17)
    at /home/user/projects/MyHANAApp/node_modules/@sap/cds/libx/_runtime/cds-services/adapter/odata-v4/okra/odata-server/invocation/CommandExecutor.js:81:18
    at /home/user/projects/MyHANAApp/node_modules/@sap/cds/libx/_runtime/cds-services/adapter/odata-v4/okra/odata-server/invocation/DispatcherCommand.js:88:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  id: '1021492',
  level: 'ERROR',
  timestamp: 1703877998669
}
```

view1.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/m/MessageToast",
    "sap/m/Dialog",
    "sap/m/Button",
    "sap/m/Input",
    "sap/m/VBox",
    "sap/m/MessageBox"
],
    /**
     * @param {typeof sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller} Controller
     */
    function (Controller,MessageToast,Dialog, Button, Input, VBox, MessageBox) {
        "use strict";

        return Controller.extend("project2.controller.View1", {
         handleAddButtonPressed : function (oEvent) {
                const that = this;
                 // Create a Dialog

                var oDialog = new Dialog({
                    title: "Add Details",
                    content: [
                        new Input({ placeholder: "Id" }),
                        new Input({ placeholder: "Email" }),
                        new Input({ placeholder: "First name" }),
                        new Input({ placeholder: "Second Name" }),
                        new Input({ placeholder: "avatar"})
                    ],
                    beginButton: new Button({
                        text: "Submit",
                        press: function() {
                            // Handle the submitted data
                            var insertData = {
                                exId: Number(oDialog.getContent()[0].getValue()),
                                exEmail: oDialog.getContent()[1].getValue(),
                                exFirst_name: oDialog.getContent()[2].getValue(),
                                exLast_name: oDialog.getContent()[3].getValue(),
                                exAvatar: oDialog.getContent()[4].getValue()
                            };
                            // console.log(updateData,typeof (updateData))
                            let sUrl = that.getOwnerComponent().getModel().getServiceUrl() + "excelFile"
                            $.ajax({
                                url: sUrl,
                                method: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                data: JSON.stringify(insertData),
                                success: function(data) {
                                    // Handle success, if needed
                                    console.log("Entity updated successfully:"+data);
                                    MessageToast.show("Entity updated successfully"+data.message);
                                    oTable.getModel("localModel").refresh(true);
                                },
                                error: function(error) {
                                    // Handle error
                                    MessageBox.error("Error updating entity:"+ error.message);
                                }
                            });
        
                            // Do something with the values (e.g., validation or further processing)

                            // Close the Dialog
                            oDialog.close();
                        }
                    }),
                    endButton: new Button({
                        text: "Cancel",
                        press: function() {
                            // Close the Dialog without processing the data
                            oDialog.close();
                        }
                    }),
                    afterClose: function() {
                    // Destroy the Dialog to avoid memory leaks
                    oDialog.destroy();
                    }
                });

                // Open the Dialog
                oDialog.open();
            },
        });
    });
```

cap-service.js

```
const cds = require('@sap/cds');
const db=cds.connect.to('db');
const {Readable,PassThrough} = require('stream');
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const moment = require('moment');

console.log('------------------hello-----------');

module.exports = cds.service.impl(srv => {


  srv.on('CREATE', 'excelFile', async (req) => {
    console.log('----------------------------creating...................');
    console.log(req.data);
    // Create a new record in the excelFile entity


    const result = await cds.run(`INSERT INTO MAVENDB_EXCELFILE VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)`,[Number(req.data.exId), req.data.exEmail, req.data.exFirst_name, req.data.exLast_name, req.data.exAvatar]);

      // Respond with a success message
      return { success: true, message: `New record inserted into excelFile entity` };

      // Respond with a failure message
   //   return { error: true, message: `Failed to insert record into excelFile entity` };

  })
})
```

cap-module.cds

```
using namespace someThingName;
entity excelFile{
    key exId : Int16;
    exEmail : String;
    exFirst_name : String;
    exLast_name : String;
    exAvatar : LargeString;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're creating the value of the primary key (`exId`) client-side. In general, primary keys should be created server-side to ensure uniqueness of the entity.